# split each key in dictionary data to stack and group

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, split, stack

I have incident data with many lists and dictionary data. Each incident has a single row with many victims and suspects characteristics (type, name, age etc.) that I need to split.

```
Incident_ID    date     #injured     type_dict                   age_dict     Name
    278  1-1-2014   1      {'0': 'Victim'}                           {'0':20}   
    279  1-1-2014   4      unknown
    280  1-1-2014   2      {'0': 'Victim', '1': 'Suspect'}           {'0':25, '1':17}  
    281  1-2-2014   4      {'0': 'Victim', '1': 'Victim', '2':'Victim', '3':'Suspect'}     {'0':27, '1':17, '2': 33, '3':40}  
    282  1-2-2014   4      {'0': 'Victim', '1': 'Victim', '2':'Victim', '3':'Suspect'}     {'0':20, '1':17, '2': 30, '3':10}  
    283  1-3-2014   3      {'0': 'Victim', '1': 'Victim', '2':'Suspect'} {'0':20, '1':31, '2': 13, '3':50}
```

I need some data engineering as below

```
1) to group by date to count (#injured) with each injury characteristics
2) to split key & value (both are strings) of dictionary data ('type_dict', 'age_dict',& name_dict etc.)
3) to make (the value of keys) as (the label or col)  
4) to stack vertically (& append) each value of keys '0', '1', '2'... 



ID    date     #injured   type_key type_value   Name          age
278  1-1-2014   1           0         Victim       aa            20  
279  1-1-2014   4         unknown
280  1-1-2014   1           0         Victim       ab            25
280  1-1-2014   1           1         Suspect      cd            17  
281  1-2-2014   1           0         Victim       ef            27 
281  1-2-2014   1           1         Victim       gh            17 
281  1-2-2014   1           2         Victim       ij            33    
281  1-2-2014   1           3         Suspect      jj            40
```

I  have tried to split the dictionary data and convert the list of values (second part of the dict) to column. The  loop ensure the columns contain type_key and  type_value of the dictionary data (type_dict).

so far, I have done with below code.

```
dictList = type_dict.items()
for key, value in type_dict.items():
    dictList.append([key, value])
```

## or

```
l=[]
for x in type_dict:
    x2=x.split(':')
    label=x2[0]
    col=x2[1]
    while len(l) < col+1:
        l.append({})
```

==>  l[col][str(len(l[col].keys()))] = label
Is this right?

Nothing has happened so please help me out.

list(type_dict.keys())

list(type_dict.values())  will split key:value pairs.

But I got either TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable  or
attribute error 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'.

I need to reorganize the data from (a single line per incident) 
to (several lines per incident) and
to merge three dictionary data grouping by incident_id. 
                 (type_key_value_list,  age_list,  name_list) like below:

```
date  incident  type_key   type_value    age   name
2014-1-1    281   '0'         'Victim'     27    ef 
            281   '1'         'Victim'     17    gh
            281   '2'         'Victim'     33    ij
            281   '3'         'Suspect'    40    jj
```

Comment: How do you know nothing has happened, what have you tried, have you looked at how l looks after the loop, if yes, how did it look like and what did you expect to see?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited some more. I got some error messages - even 'split' method didn't go through.

Comment: the type_dict entries seem to be dictionaries themselves sometimes, not strings separated with ":" , you'll need to iterate over them too.

Comment: list(type_dict.keys())    
list(type_dict.values())

Comment: You may also want to edit your code block; I can't drop it in and test it (this isn't the Code Review SE site) or give feedback on possible changes to your methodology when it's unclear how you're going about it. For example, on comments in code, comment them out (I'm assuming 'is this right?' is a comment).

Comment: To get average age by incident_id and by date, I need to manipulate the data by type and age like:
  res = {key: value + "  " + df_age[key] + "  "+ df_status[key] for key, value in df_type.items()}

Comment: # initialising _dictionary 
ini_dict = {'a' : 'akshat', 'b' : 'bhuvan', 'c': 'chandan'} 
  
# printing iniial_dictionary 
print("intial_dictionary", str(ini_dict)) 
  
# split dictionary into keys and values 
keys, values = zip(*ini_dict.items()) 
  
# printing keys and values separately 
print ("keys : ", str(keys)) 
print ("values : ", str(values))